# Can't find method on extension class:

Tags: android, native, game-maker

Hi Im making an android native extension in Gamemaker: Studio and when I run the game and try to use the extension i get this error code in the runner command window:

Can't find method on extension class:folderLoader[double, double]

It does not crash the game or throw any other errors, it just can't find my method in the java file. this is how I have it set up:

edit extension package properties-general tab-

name- DirectoryPicker

android checkbox ticked

inject to manifest-

```
<activity
android:name="${YYAndroidPackageName}.DirectoryPicker"
android:label="DirectoryPicker" />
```

inject to gradle (to activate my styles.xml)-

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

edit extension package properties-android tab-

Class name- DirectoryPicker

Permissions- android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

edit extension file properties box-

name- DirectoryPicker.extension.gmx

init function- set to folderLoader

copys to- ticked android and android yyc boxes only

edit extension functions box-

name- folderLoader

external name- folderLoader

help- folderLoader(double FolderOnly, double ShowHidden)

return type box- selected double

key and value box- argument 0 double argument1 double

the calling code for an object's left mouse pressed event:

```
folderLoader(1.0, 0.0);
```

the async event in the same object (set to social event):

```
var type2 = string(async_load[? "type2"])
var data2 = string(async_load[? "folder"])
if type2 == "folderFound"
{ 
var text = data2;
}
```

the java file- named DirectoryPicker.java

```
package ${YYAndroidPackageName};
import ${YYAndroidPackageName}.R;
import ${YYAndroidPackageName}.RunnerActivity;
import com.yoyogames.runner.RunnerJNILib;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DirectoryPicker extends ListActivity {

private static final int EVENT_OTHER_SOCIAL = 70;
public static final String ONLY_DIRS = "onlyDirs";
public static final String SHOW_HIDDEN = "showHidden";
public static final String CHOSEN_DIRECTORY = "chosenDir";
public static final int PICK_DIRECTORY = 43522432;
private File dir;
private boolean onlyDirs = true;
private boolean showHidden = false;


public void folderLoader(double yesOrNo,double noOrYes)
{
if(yesOrNo == 0.0) onlyDirs = false;
if(yesOrNo == 1.0) onlyDirs = true;
if(noOrYes == 0.0) showHidden = false;
if(noOrYes == 1.0) showHidden = true;
findFolders();
}

public void findFolders() {

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        File Root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        dir = new File(Root.getAbsolutePath());
    }
if (extras != null) {
    showHidden = extras.getBoolean(SHOW_HIDDEN, false);
    onlyDirs = extras.getBoolean(ONLY_DIRS, true);
}

setContentView(R.layout.chooser_list);
setTitle(dir.getAbsolutePath());
Button btnChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
String name = dir.getName();
if(name.length() == 0)
    name = "No folders found";
btnChoose.setText(name);
btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        returnDir(dir.getAbsolutePath());
    }
});

ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

if(!dir.canRead()) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    String msg = "Could not read folders.";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    return;
}

final ArrayList<File> files = filter(dir.listFiles(), onlyDirs, showHidden);
String[] names = names(files);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, names));


lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(!files.get(position).isDirectory())
            return;
        String path = files.get(position).getAbsolutePath();
        Intent intent = new Intent((RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity), DirectoryPicker.class);
        intent.putExtra(DirectoryPicker.SHOW_HIDDEN, showHidden);
        intent.putExtra(DirectoryPicker.ONLY_DIRS, onlyDirs);
        (RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity).startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_DIRECTORY);
    }
});
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if(requestCode == PICK_DIRECTORY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    String path = (String) extras.get(DirectoryPicker.CHOSEN_DIRECTORY);
    returnDir(path);
int dsMapIndex = RunnerJNILib.jCreateDsMap(null, null, null);
RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString( dsMapIndex, "type2", "folderFound" );
RunnerJNILib.DsMapAddString( dsMapIndex, "folder", path );
RunnerJNILib.CreateAsynEventWithDSMap(dsMapIndex, EVENT_OTHER_SOCIAL);
}
}

private void returnDir(String path) {
Intent result = new Intent();
result.putExtra(CHOSEN_DIRECTORY, path);
setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
finish();
}

public ArrayList<File> filter(File[] file_list, boolean onlyDirs, boolean showHidden) {
ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
for(File file: file_list) {
    if(onlyDirs && !file.isDirectory())
        continue;
    if(!showHidden && file.isHidden())
        continue;
    files.add(file);
}
Collections.sort(files);
return files;
}

public String[] names(ArrayList<File> files) {
String[] names = new String[files.size()];
int i = 0;
for(File file: files) {
    names[i] = file.getName();
    i++;
}
return names;
}
}
```

There are 2 related xml files that i put in the layout folder which i put in the res folder, which is in the AndroidSource folder.
I have also downloaded some extensions to see how they did them, and they all have a file in the android source folder called yymanifest.xml, which is generated by gamemaker, this file never gets created in my extension project, I've tried saving, exporting the extension and re importing it but the file is never there, and it's not a file you can make yourself, gamemaker has to produce it when it makes the extension, but how can I get it to do this???

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: have you tried clearing the cache before compiling.  Also can double take decimal values?

Answer (score 3):

Well everything seems fine you need to mention you folder in menifest file.

Comment: ok cool and thanks!! I neglected to do that I'll give it a try

Comment: Ok so I've been working on this for days, still the same error, : Can't find method on extension class:null. I know through working with java that null exceptions occur when you reference an un initialized variable, but as far as i can see everything's initialized, I've updated my java file a few times so I'm going to edit my original post question with the new file and other things I've tried